# qml displaying listdata with heading

Tags: qt

i am new to Qt.i have to display a huge data in qml listview and that data is divided in some headings.i wana know that how to make such listview to display heading then his data...

Regards

Adnan Shoukat

Comment: you can create heterogeneous list, where list header is also part of model,just rendered differently, here is link"http://cdumez.blogspot.com/2010/11/heterogeneous-list-model-in-qml.html"

Answer (score 0):

There is section.* properties in QML ListView. It automatically creates sections in view with section headers (defined in section.delegate property).